# Use template tags within template tags?

Tags: python, django

I'm writting a page in Django, and I have a template for loading CSS (and another one for JS) which all I need to do is send the file path as a variable. It works great when I pass a link to somewhere, but when I need to use a static file, I have a problem because I need to use a template tag within another. How can I find a solution?

```
{% include "css" with src="{% static "css/styles.css" %}" %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% static "css/styles.css" as styles %}
{% include "css" with src=styles %}
```